# How can I know the count of up voted answers on questions where an answer of mine has a positive score?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, up-votes

I want to know the total no of up votes given by me to the answers on questions where an answer of mine has a positive score.

I want this count to see the eligibility of the silver badge **sportsmanship**.

Is it possible to know this? Is there anyway to get this count?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to get an actual count. There's nothing on your profile that will give this information.

However, there's a Data Explorer query that will give you a list of eligible posts that, if you upvote, will count towards the badge.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65472/how-close-am-i-to-the-sportsmanship-badge

So the only way to get a number is to run down this list and count up how many you have upvoted.

Note that it's not possible get an actual progress indicator since votes are anonymized. So the data explorer cannot determine how many of them you have actually upvoted.

---

**As a final disclaimer:** Do not abuse this query to serially upvote everything to game the badge.

IIRC, I've seen somebody suspended for voting irregularies while having "Sportsmanship" as the most recent badge.

Comment: The given query is incorrect. And as you already mentioned votes are anonymized, we can't get it even by data explorer.

Comment: You cannot *get* sportsmanship progress from the Data Explorer since you cannot query for your own votes on it..

Comment: The query gives you which posts that, if you voted on, will count towards the badge. It doesn't tell you how many you have voted on and how close you are to 100.

Comment: But i want the count of my up votes towards this badge.

Comment: @EdwinAlex That's not possible. Votes are anonymized. So the data explorer cannot determine which ones you have already upvoted. The only way to determine if you have upvoted something is to check it while logged in.

Comment: But it gives wrong count. From this morning, i have been put 30 votes for this category. But it shows only 21.

Comment: @EdwinAlex - First of all, **DON'T** upvote other answers only to get badge. Also, Data is updated monthly.

Comment: @EdwinAlex Then some of the posts you voted on are not eligible. (I can't speak for the query since I didn't write it.) But you seriously ***should not be gaming the badge*** like this.

Comment: AFAICT, I've seen people get suspended for serially upvoting to get the badge. The query should only be used a sort of hint, not as something to help you abuse votes.

Comment: I know that. We should not do like this. But i am curious to know these kind of things. I searched my entire profile page. There is no option to get this count. That's why i did like this. I am sorry.

Comment: Also in this way, we cannot judge others voting know. They may think that some point is helpful for the posts. So they will give up vote. I have seen so many undeserved posts got many upvotes.